# Proper way for seamless animations in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to achieve the following DOM mutation using ReactJS, and animate it so that it cannot be noticeable by the end user.

```
<RootComponent>
  <MyComponent id="a"/>
  <div>
    <MyComponent id="b"/>
  </div>
  <MyComponent id="c"/>
</RootComponent>
```

to

```
<RootComponent>
  <MyComponent id="a2"/>
  <div>
    <MyComponent id="a"/>
  </div>
  <MyComponent id="c"/>
</RootComponent>
```

I successfully handle the animation (by moving the DOM Node around through the parent) and replace `b` with `a`, along with creating a new `a2`component.

The problem is, as soon as I ask React to rerender the root component (by placing `a2`), I run into an invariant violation. Indeed, I mutated the DOM manually, and data-reactids might be shuffled.

How could I complete such a workflow following React's best practices ?

Comment: Try to animate without manipulating DOM first, then trigger a re-render when the animation is complete so the DOM movement won’t be visible for the end user.

Comment: Would `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` help with the animation: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html If using basic if/then or ?: statements to change DOM nodes you shouldn't be seeing any errors. Post a working code sample.